# symfony2 form builder date type

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building a booking system for a hotel website that contains rezervations ability. Rezervations form contains name, last name etc... and date of arrival and date of departure. That is a 'date' type in the form builder that constructs three select tags; month, day, year in that order. I would like to customize it in various ways.

I would like to change the order of the select tags to be: days, months, years.
I would like to change the default english months to my local ones (i'm croatian).

So, how do I do that in the createFormBuilder() funciton? I tried adding some 'choice' keys to the parameter array, but it keeps sending errors that the expected parameter is long but string given.

Also, any advice would be welcome from anyone who worked with dates in forms in symfony2, pitfalls, common mistakes, should i use it or should i not, stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking fore

```
$builder->add('date_field', 'date', array(
    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
));
```

Moreover you can add various type of customization to your `date_field` field such have not three differents selects but one and so on.

Take a look [here](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html)